# Is it true that a child is affected if the mother commits sins?

Tags: shiism, sin, children

### This is from a Shia point of view

---

This is a statement I found from [hubeali.com](https://hubeali.com/articles/chapter-6-family-life.pdf):

> It is narrated from Amir-ul-momaneen that a child gets ill if the mother commits a sin.
>
> (Huliya-tul-Mutaqeen, Allam Majlisi, Urdu translation, pp.144.)

**Question:** Is this belief in Shia Islam true and why do they believe this?

If they do believe this, then **children will be harmed** and the only way to stop it is to not sin so a mother would have to commit no sins but that is impossible for a normal Muslim to be infallible.

Abu Huraira reported:

> The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “By Him in whose hand is my soul, if you did not sin Allah would replace you with people who would sin and they would seek the forgiveness of Allah and He would forgive them.”
>
> Source: Sahih Muslim 2749
>
> Grade: Sahih (authentic )according to Muslim

Comment: Are you only looking for a shia point of view?

Comment: Yes because the website I found it from was from a Shia point of view

Comment: The [author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad-Baqer_Majlesi) of that statement (according to the pdf). Maybe you should ask how the words "sin" and "gets ill" are interpreted in that statement. (Because its translated to english from Urdu). And then maybe ask how one would balance that view with the interpretation of that hadith you stated from Sahih Muslim. Also it is good to know that even from the shia point of view, there might be many different opinions about this. – Kilise 12 mins ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar hadith which is quoted (as Imam Ali said):

> فِي الْمَرَضِ يُصيبُ الصَبيَّ، كَفّارَةٌ لِوالِدَيْهِ
>
> The illness of the child is the Kaffarah of (his/her) parents's sin.

Such affairs can be relative. It means, in some (complicate) issues, it is tough for Aql (intellect) to give a decisive Hokms (or to have a complete perception regarding the Hekmah –wisdom- of Allah’s advisability).

**E.g.**, what is the sin of the child whose parents have drunk alcoholic liquor or some other dangerous material/act which can be led to born an imperfective child?
Albeit there can be more explanation/reasons to resolve the query, but I presume the above-mentioned example (of an imperfective child) can solve the query.
I appreciate such constructive question.

**Reference:**

- [www.askdin.com](http://www.askdin.com/showthread.php?t=5460)